# Notation for different versions of the adjoint operator (musical isomorphism)

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, differential-forms, index-notation

Let $T:V \to W$ be a  linear map between two finite-dimensional vector spaces. The dual map of $T$ is $T^*:W^* \to V^*$. $V^*$ map be identified with $V$ in an unique way, by the mapping $\mathcal I_V:V^* \to V$, such that
$$
\langle \mathcal I_V(\phi), v \rangle = \phi(v),\forall v\in V,
$$
and similarly we have $\mathcal I_W$ for $W$. We write $\phi^\sharp$ for $\mathcal I_V(\phi)$ and similarly for elements of $W^*$, and this is called musical isomorphism.

Question: what notation should one use for the composition
$$
\mathcal I_V\circ T^* \circ\mathcal I_W^{-1} ?
$$
I find it difficult because I am raising an index of $T^*$ and lowering the other index, so I cannot use a simple $\sharp$ or $\flat$.

Comment: Your composition is precisely the (metric) adjoint so it is usually denoted by $T^{*}$ in linear algebra and differential geometry. It satisfies $\left< Tv, w \right>_{W} = \left< v, T^{*}w \right>_{V}$ (and this property defines it uniquely). When people don't want to confuse the dual map and the adjoint, they use different notations for both maps. For example, the dual space can be denoted by $V^{\vee}$, the dual map by $T^{\vee}$ and the adjoint ($\mathcal{I}_V \circ T^{\vee} \circ \mathcal{I}_W^{-1}$) by $T^{*}$.

Answer (score 1):

As levap says, this is the [adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint), and you want your vector spaces to be inner product spaces but you haven't specified that. My preferred convention is to use $T^{\ast} : W^{\ast} \to V^{\ast}$ for the dual and $T^{\dagger} : W \to V$ for the adjoint but this isn't universal.